# Prove $f_\infty: A_\infty \rightarrow B_\infty$ is a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Update: I was given some hints at how to approach this problem

$A_\infty $ and $B_\infty$ are sets, not maps. (which is strange because there are function definitions coming into play here)

The definition of $f_\infty$ is the restriction of $f$ with the domain and codomain restricted.

1.) Show that $f_\infty $is defined, i.e., if $a \in A_\infty$, then $f(a) \in B_\infty$.

2.) Show that $f_\infty$ is injective, clear because $f_\infty $ is a restriction of the
     injective function f.

3.) Show that $f_\infty$ is onto, i.e., if $ b \in B_\infty$, then there is an $a \in A_\infty$
     and $f(a) = b$. So, show that there is an appropriate element in $A$ that maps to
     $b$, and then show that it even belong to $X_\infty.$

Original Attempt:

I am using the Cantor-Schroder-Beenstein Theorem to prove $f_\infty: A_\infty \rightarrow B_\infty$ is a bijection.

The cases of $f_+: A_+ \rightarrow B_+$ and $f_-: A_- \rightarrow B_-$  being bijections are already done.

The theorem states that for any sets $A$ and $B$, if there exist injections from $A$ into $B$ and from $B$ to $A$, then $\mid A \mid = \mid B \mid$

From definition 5.4.5 A function $f: x \rightarrow y$ with the property

$(\forall x_1, x_2 \in X)( x_1 \neq x_2 \rightarrow f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$

is an injection of $X$ into $Y$.

So, from $A $ into $B$ I have,

$f: A \rightarrow B$ with the property

$(\forall a_1, a_2 \in A)( a_1 \neq a_2 \rightarrow f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$

and from $B$ into $A$, I have

$f: B \rightarrow A$ with the property

$(\forall b_1, b_2 \in B)( b_1 \neq b_2 \rightarrow f(b_1) \neq f(b_2)$

Anyway,

For $A \in A_+$  the predecessor sequence terminates in A

For $B \in B_+$  the predecessor sequence terminates in A

The $f_+ $ is the restriction of $f$ to $A_+$, and $f_+$ is a function $A_+ \rightarrow B_+$
so the sequence is $(a \in A_+)$ is $(a,...x)$

Suppose $f_+$ is onto (surjection). The we pick $b \in B_+$ and our sequence is $(f(a),a,...x)$

Since  $b=f(a) $ and $a \in A_+$, $f_+ : A_+ \rightarrow B_+$ is a bijection.

For $A \in A_-$  the predecessor sequence terminates in B

For $B \in B_-$  the predecessor sequence terminates in B

Suppose $g_: B_- \rightarrow A_-$ is well defined and a bijection. Then for $b \in B$, the sequence for $b$ is $(b,a,b_1,a_1...b_m)$. Now set $y_(b)=g(b)$. The sequence for $g(b)$ is $(g(b),b,...b_m)$, so $g(b) \in A$.

Now suppose $g_-$ is is an injection. There is a restriction of an injective map $g$. For. $a \in A$ the sequence of $a$ will be $(a,b,...b_m)$ and $g(b_1) = a$ and $a \in A$. Therefore $g_: B_- \rightarrow A_-$ is a bijection

For $A \in A_\infty$  the predecessor sequence doesn't terminate.

For $B \in B_\infty$  the predecessor sequence doesn't terminate.

So now I got to prove that  $f_\infty: A_\infty \rightarrow B_\infty$ is a bijection. So I already know that $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$ are both going to be a surjection and an injection. But, since the predecessor sequence doesn't terminate, that means it could go on forever. I could have something like $(a,b,a_1,b_a,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3,...) $

Maybe I think for $a \in A$ the sequence of $a$ is $(a,b,......b_m)$ so $g(b_1) = a $ and $a \in A_\infty$. and for $b \in B$, the sequence of $b$ will be $(b,a,b_1,a_1,...a_m$. Since $g(a_1) = b$ and $b \in B_\infty$, then $g: A_\infty \rightarrow B_\infty$

This is where I am kind of lost since I already mentioned that the $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$ aren't going to terminate at all, so their sequence will continue, but how do I show that? Do I list a bunch of terms for $A$ and $B$ and then create a surjection and injection map?

With the hints, would that mean that $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$ are restricted in the domain and codomain as well, and the sequence or element belongs inside of $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$ ?